# How to force close windows phone app programmatically if version is not compatible

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I am developing a windows phone app for windows phone 8.

**Here i want force close the app if any one browsing my app through windows phone 7.**

I want to check the version of the phone and i want take person in to main screen if he have windows phone 8 otherwise i want show him a alert(MessageBox) saying that your phone is not compatible on clicking on "ok" button app will be closed.

**Edit:**

I am developing the app which targets windows phone 7.1 and 8,so how can i stop the person who is browsing my app using windows phone 7?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to prevent installing the app on Windows Phone 7?

Answer (score 1):

If you develop the app targetting Windows Phone 8, the user won't be able to install it in a device running Windows Phone 7. So you don't have to worry about it.

In order to be executable in both platforms, the app has to target Windows Phone 7.1. But that doesn't make sense in your case. If you want only Windows Phone 8 users to use your app, set it's target to Windows Phone 8, and it will only execute in that platform.

Comment: I developed app for the windows phone 7.1 and 8, it will work for both so can app store stops the person who is trying to download from windows phone 7?

Comment: Why don't you upgrade it into WP 8 project? And why do you want to prevent WP 7.5 users from using it?

Answer (score 0):

Technically you cannot do that. While it's possible to check the version and throw an unhandled exception, the certification guidelines do not allow unhandled exceptions. The correct way to handle this would be to make your app only target WP8 to begin with, so that WP7 users can't download it at all.